# AngularJS $location.search does not work with query parameters in the middle of URL

Tags: angularjs

We have a legacy webapp written in AngularJs and it doesn't uses the HTML5 mode in location provider. When we have the URL in following valid format $location.search() returns empty object

```
https://my.domain.com/path/index.html?param=value#hashpart
```

But when the URL is in following non-conventional way it returns the object {'param':'value'}

```
https://my.domain.com/path/index.html#hashpart?param=value
```

[RFC3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.5) says the fragment should come at the end of the URI

Can anyone help us to understand why? We need the URL in the first format.